# Distinct function in dplyr package

Tags: r, distinct

I'm trying to get get unique values for 2 columns. I get them when I write it separately but it doesn't work for both in the same command. I do it like this:

```
dataname  %>% 
     select(column name, column name) %>% 
     distinct() %>% 
     summarise(name=n(), name=n())
```

In this way, I only get unique values for the first column. What is the problem?

Comment: Please try `base::unique(c(df$col1, df$col2))`

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Your `select` shows the same 'column name'.  Not clear without a small reproducible example